# Removed a partition with GParted. Ubuntu still tries to mount it

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, gparted

This is my problem. When I installed my Ubuntu 14.04 partition coming back from Windows 7, I decided to leave my Games partition alone and have it be there.

I then realized having a root partition, a `/home` partition and a 300GB gaming partition was not a great idea seeing as the puny 80GB `/home` partition got used up fast enough with MKV files.

I then booted into a GParted disc, removed the `/mnt/Games` partition and made the `/home` partition 300GB bigger.

Now, Ubuntu always tries to mount it at boot (I had it automount on boot) and gives me an error every time I boot up.

How do I go by fixing this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the `/etc/fstab` file with a text editor as root (for example, `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab`) and put `#` in front of the entry for the partition that you don't have any more, the one that says `/mnt/games/`